# How to ensure that all of the cell content shows in an Excel contenttype page

Tags: visualforce, table, excel

I am exporting a page as Excel page as described [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_styling_content_type.htm) (using `contenttype`). I am unsure how to ensure that the contents of the cells are showing. After opening the file, I could change it manually, by setting the cell height to `Auto-fit` and setting the cell contents to `wrap`, but I would like to do this automatically.

I am guessing there must be a property that can be set in `style` which is explicitly for Excel which will define these two properties. Perhaps something similar to the [`mso-number-format`](http://cosicimiento.blogspot.jp/2008/11/styling-excel-cells-with-mso-number.html) property. Note that I am currently using standard `html table` instead of a `apex:pageBlockTable`.

If anyone knows anything about this, I would also be grateful if you let me know **how** you found out about this. I have had difficulty finding documentation around this area.

Edit, I have figured out that `white-space: normal;` makes excel wrap the text (half of the solution). I just need to figure out the automatic height now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to the question. The first is to wrap the cell contents:

`white-space: normal;`

The second part was because I had tried to set the height of the cell manually. Together with the first part, if there is no `height` property set, then the height becomes automatic.